# Unable to Publish Serverless ASP.Net Core WebApi template

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am learning serverless framework with ASP.Net core and having problem publishing the default project that is generated by Dotnet CLI. I have already configured IAM role and AWS CLI. My default zone is configured as us-west-2. I am not sure if that might make a difference.

I am generating the serverless project using the command

```
dotnet new serverless.AspNetCoreWebAPI --name Test
```

This generates a new ASP.Net Core Web API Project. If I navigate into the project directory and try to publish it using the command below, nothing is created in the CloudFormation stacks ...

```
dotnet lambda deploy-serverless
```

I get the following output

```
    Amazon Lambda Tools for .NET Core applications (5.2.0)
Project Home: https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli, https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet

Enter CloudFormation Stack Name: (CloudFormation stack name for an AWS Serverless application)
test
Enter S3 Bucket: (S3 bucket to upload the build output)
test-s3
Warning: Unable to determine region for bucket test-s3, assuming bucket is in correct region: Access Denied
Processing CloudFormation resource AspNetCoreFunction
Initiate packaging of . for resource AspNetCoreFunction
Executing publish command
Deleted previous publish folder
... invoking 'dotnet publish', working folder '/Users/afraz/RiderProjects/Microserver/test/src/Test/./bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish'
... dotnet publish --output "/Users/afraz/RiderProjects/Microserver/test/src/Test/./bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish" --configuration "Release" --framework "netcoreapp3.1" /p:GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles=true --runtime linux-x64 --self-contained false
... publish: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.2+b60ddb6f4 for .NET
... publish: Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
... publish:   Determining projects to restore...
... publish:   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
... publish:   Test -> /Users/afraz/RiderProjects/Microserver/test/src/Test/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/Test.dll
... publish:   Test -> /Users/afraz/RiderProjects/Microserver/test/src/Test/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents.dll).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx Test.pdb).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx Test.runtimeconfig.json).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx Test).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore.dll).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx Test.dll).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx web.config).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx appsettings.json).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx Amazon.Lambda.ApplicationLoadBalancerEvents.dll).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.dll).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx Test.deps.json).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx Amazon.Lambda.Core.dll).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx appsettings.Development.json).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.dll).
Zipping publish folder /Users/afraz/RiderProjects/Microserver/test/src/Test/./bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish to /var/folders/9t/7fw58bfn40v7tyz74qh4qhym0000gn/T/AspNetCoreFunction-CodeUri-Or-ImageUri-637758644748800220.zip
... zipping:   adding: Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents.dll (deflated 57%)
... zipping:   adding: Test.pdb (deflated 48%)
... zipping:   adding: Test.runtimeconfig.json (deflated 31%)
... zipping:   adding: Test (deflated 61%)
... zipping:   adding: Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore.dll (deflated 50%)
... zipping:   adding: Test.dll (deflated 55%)
... zipping:   adding: web.config (deflated 40%)
... zipping:   adding: appsettings.json (deflated 28%)
... zipping:   adding: Amazon.Lambda.ApplicationLoadBalancerEvents.dll (deflated 49%)
... zipping:   adding: Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.dll (deflated 44%)
... zipping:   adding: aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json (deflated 46%)
... zipping:   adding: Test.deps.json (deflated 91%)
... zipping:   adding: Amazon.Lambda.Core.dll (deflated 42%)
... zipping:   adding: appsettings.Development.json (deflated 13%)
... zipping:   adding: Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.dll (deflated 57%)
Created publish archive (/var/folders/9t/7fw58bfn40v7tyz74qh4qhym0000gn/T/AspNetCoreFunction-CodeUri-Or-ImageUri-637758644748800220.zip).
Lambda project successfully packaged: /var/folders/9t/7fw58bfn40v7tyz74qh4qhym0000gn/T/AspNetCoreFunction-CodeUri-Or-ImageUri-637758644748800220.zip
Uploading to S3. (Bucket: test-s3 Key: Test/AspNetCoreFunction-CodeUri-Or-ImageUri-637758644748800220-637758644771656260.zip)
Error uploading to Test/AspNetCoreFunction-CodeUri-Or-ImageUri-637758644748800220-637758644771656260.zip in bucket test-s3: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

This is the **serverless.template** file

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.",
  "Parameters": {},
  "Conditions": {},
  "Resources": {
    "AspNetCoreFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "Test::Test.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore3.1",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [
          "AWSLambda_FullAccess"
        ],
        "Events": {
          "ProxyResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          },
          "RootResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "ApiURL": {
      "Description": "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have not made any changes to the code so I am not sure exactly what the problem is and why the project is not getting published. Looking through the logs the only part that seems off is this warning but in the **serverless.template** file there is nothing related to **S3 configuration**

```
Warning: Unable to determine region for bucket test-s3, assuming bucket is in correct region: Access Denied
Processing CloudFormation resource AspNetCoreFunction
```

Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Comment: Not sure where do you trying to publish on `Azure` or `AWS` may I know are you following any official sample for that? Share the information to assist you on this.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron This is one of the articles that I followed but I haven't made any code changes. https://dev.to/sunilkumarmedium/build-a-serverless-dotnet-core-web-api-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-22dd

I am trying to publish to AWS

Comment: Did you check if the user has permission to upload files to the s3 bucket?

Comment: Did you verify if the bucket is created in the correct region?

Comment: @Chetan yeah I did, nothing was created at all

Comment: You might want to follow the article again. Your serverless template file is a lot different than the one in the article. The file in the article takes care of creating s3 bucket if not already exists. While yours don't have that provision.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that in the article the author made some code changes but in my case I just created a new project with CLI and tried to publish it which should work but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting same error. Got it working though by creating bucket before the publish command

```html
#Check if the bucket exists
if(aws --profile $AWSProfile s3api head-bucket --bucket $bucketName --region ap-southeast-2 2>&1 | findstr 'An error occurred'){
        Write-Host "bucket does not exist or permission error."
        aws s3api --profile $AWSProfile create-bucket --bucket $bucketName --region ap-southeast-2 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=ap-southeast-2
        Write-Host 'created'
}
```